# Adding index on a compound index on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I created a compound index on my db using:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({a:1,b:1})
```

Now I realized I need another level in the composition:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({a:1,b:1,c:1})
```

Will Mongodb create a whole new index, or will it know to modify the existing one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling [`ensureIndex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex) with different fields will create a new index.

You can confirm this after running both commands by using [`getIndexes`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/#db.collection.getIndexes) to see what indexes exist for your collection:

```js
db.collection.getIndexes()
```

If you no longer want the original index, you can drop it using:

```js
db.collection.dropIndex({a:1,b:1})
```

Comment: Just to add to this, the index `{a:1,b:1,c:1}` will behave just like `{a:1,b:1}` (in addition to supporting `c`) since [mongo will use index prefixes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes).